# how to show the document ID after get TF-IDF ,cosine_similarity? python

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, nltk, tf-idf

I calculate TF-IDF for both query string and a few documents.
I would like to calculate the cosine similarity and display the document ID list from the most relevant to query to less relevant.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
## load the documents (around 200 txt) from path
cranInp=[]
path="D:\\Desktop\\try\\web"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    textdir=path+"\\"+file
    f=open(textdir).read()
    # print f
    cranInp.append(f)


Vcount = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words = 'english')
countMatrix = Vcount.fit_transform(cranInp)


 Query = "in summarizing theoretical and experimental work on the behaviour of a typical aircraft structure in a noise environment is it possible to develop a design procedure ."
 queryVects  = Vcount.transform(Query)

k = 50
cosMattf = cosine_similarity(queryVects,countMatrix)
```

how to get the list of top K ( k=50) document such as [12.txt,34.txt,89.txt,90.txt....45.txt]  the size of the list is 50.

from most relevant to less relevant such as 12.txt has the lowest cosine distance and it is the most relevant document to the query.

Comment: In parallel to the contents (`cranInp`), create a list with the file names in the same order. Then use numpy's [`argsort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) to sort the file names by their respective cosine similarity.

Comment: i don't think has to do with `nltk` ;P